# Need to detect drop location in reference to Grid Element in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I am creating Grid elements dynamically onto a stack panel. When an object is dropped on the stack panel, it fires an event that needs to determine where the drop point was in reference to the Grid element on the  StackPanel. I am using WPF, so that might make some answers different.

For example, I have the following code that is called when an object is dropped onto a grid element(that has been previously created dynamically).

```
/*Handles Drop Event From Grid Item*/
    private void Grid_Drop(object sender,DragEventArgs e)
    {
        Object droppedData = e.getData(typeof(Object)); //This part is not important

        /*Get the Grid that was dropped on*/
        Grid grid = (Grid)sender;

        /*Translate Drop Point in reference to Stack Panel*/
        Point dropPoint = this.TranslatePoint(e.getPosition(this),StackPanel));

    }
```

Here is where I have stopped, I need to calculate something like the following

```
       IF dropPoint IS ABOVE THE MIDDLE POINT OF THE GRID
            DO SOMETHING
       ELSE IF THE dropPoint IS BELOW THE MIDDLE POINT OF THE GRID
            DO SOMETHING
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you get the relative position to the grid, rather than the stack panel and compare that point.y to grid.actualheight/2 to see if it is above or below?

Comment: Well the stack panel actually has a use outside of this problem, If I were to  use the Y coordinate of the drop point, then I wouldn't have an accurate location of the grid element, only an accurate location of the drop point. Correct me if I misunderstood your suggestion.

Comment: After taking some time, I realized what you were saying, and that is correct. Thank you.